# Basic Calculation for WPF Polygon: Area and Centroid

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, polygon

The System.Windows.Shapes.Shape namespace provides access to **Polygon** object that can be used in XAML or code.

Is there a Microsoft library that provides some very basic calculations on a Polygon like area or centriod?

My preference is to not re-implement these functions myself or copy a math/geometry library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`RenderedGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.renderedgeometry.aspx) property returns a [`Geometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) object, which itself has a [`GetArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.getarea.aspx) method.

There doesn't seem to be anything to compute the centroid, but it should be quite easy to do, based on the `Points` property of the `Polygon`:

```
Point centroid =
    polygon.Points.Aggregate(
        new { xSum = 0.0, ySum = 0.0, n = 0 },
        (acc, p) => new
        {
            xSum = acc.xSum + p.X,
            ySum = acc.ySum + p.Y,
            n = acc.n + 1
        },
        acc => new Point(acc.xSum / acc.n, acc.ySum / acc.n));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how to calculate the area and the centriod; this gets me started.

Answer (score 2):

I posted some linq-ified geometric operations in this post:

[How to Zip one IEnumerable with itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768834/how-to-zip-one-ienumerable-with-itself)

The centroid computation I posted is different from the one that @Thomas Levesque posted.  I got it from [Wikipedia - Centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid).  His looks a lot simpler than the one that I posted.

Here is my algorithm (it makes use of SignedArea and Pairwise from the link above):

```
  public static Position Centroid(IEnumerable<Position> pts) 
  { 
    double a = SignedArea(pts); 

    var  c = pts.Pairwise((p1, p2) => new  
                                      {  
                                        x = (p1.X + p2.X) * (p1.X * p2.Y - p2.X * p1.Y),  
                                        y = (p1.Y + p2.Y) * (p1.X * p2.Y - p2.X * p1.Y)    
                                      }) 
                .Aggregate((t1, t2) => new  
                                       {  
                                         x = t1.x + t2.x,  
                                         y = t1.y + t2.y  
                                       }); 

    return new Position(1.0 / (a * 6.0) * c.x, 1.0 / (a * 6.0) * c.y); 
  }
```

There are also some other algorithms at that link that you might find useful.